# PHP Googlebase Get the products without user login

Tags: php, google-base

This is my requirement ( I searched a lot but I could not find a solution)

I have a merchant account in google base where I added my products.
In my site I want to list those products by querying the googlebase feeds.
And the customer should be able to get those products without any authentication.

I tried the sample code given in the google code, but it is asking for authentication when I run the code in the browser. Instead I want to do it in my code itself. Which authentication method I should use in my code ?

Regards
Binoy

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but the answer may help someone else.

Just authenticate with your own details in the code. The user won't see your credentials but GoogleBase will return the products that you have in your account.